# IndexOutofBounds exception when adding an Image to an ArrayList

Tags: java, image, graphics, arraylist

I am trying to add an image object (a picture of a turtle) to an ArrayList, and have each separate object appear somewhere else on the screen. When I add the image to ArrayList, I get an IndexOutofBounds error, and only one of the objects appear on the screen.

I've tried setting the index to a smaller value, but then only one Turtle appears on the screen.

```
ArrayList<Turtle> list = new ArrayList<Turtle>();

public void update(Graphics g) {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    int r = randomNumber.nextInt(50);
        list.add(i+r, turtle);
        turtle.update(g);
    }
}
```

The method update in my Turtle class is as follows:

```
public void update(Graphics g) {
    // Move the turtle
    if (x < dest_x) {
        x += 1;
    } else if (x > dest_x) {
        x -= 1;
    }

    if (y < dest_y) {
        y += 1;
    } else if (y > dest_y) {
        y -= 1;
    }

    // Draw the turtle
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, 100, 100, null);
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance. Let me know if you need more information to sort this problem.

Comment: `i+r` is probably bigger than the size of your list.

Comment: `ArrayList` is more like a `List` than an array. It's only as big as the number of items in it. Don't be confused by the `initialCapacity` field which defines how much MEMORY is allocated. You're still constrained to numbering the items from 0 to ArrayList.size-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `add` appears to be wrong:

```
list.add(i+r, turtle);
```

You are adding a random number to the index, which almost certainly is greater than the size of the list.  Quoting from [the Javadocs for the `add` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)):

> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range
> (index < 0 || index > size())

Comment: That makes sense, but then how do I make the objects I have just entered in the array appear on different places?

Is there some way I can make the add call change the x and y value of the drawImage call?

Comment: The `x` and `y` values have nothing to do with the object's position in an `ArrayList`.  Change the `x` and `y` values yourself, as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

With a call like

```
ArrayList<Turtle> list = new ArrayList<Turtle>();
...
list.add(i+r, turtle);
```

where `i+r` might evaluate to a number bigger than 0 on the first iteration, you will right away get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. The javadoc states:

> **IndexOutOfBoundsException** - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index > size())